# Dividing list by list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, typeerror

To divide every item of a list by an item in another list, on the same place I have the following piece of code:

```
def calc_cosine(up_part, down_part):
    cosines = list(map(truediv, up_part, down_part))
    return cosines
```

up_part:

```
[4.0, 4.0, 2.0, 5.0]
```

down_part:

```
[6.0, 8.94427190999916, 6.928203230275509, 7.348469228349535]
```

output:

```
[0.6666666666666666, 0.4472135954999579, 0.2886751345948129, 0.6804138174397716]
```

However, when I use this function in a flask application it gives a `TypeError`.

Does someone know a way to divide each list element by the element of the second list that is in the same place, only then by using a `for` loop?

Comment: Hi Arthur, please provide an example of an expected output for a given set of inputs. This will help to clarify your question.

Comment: Check the indentation of your code

Comment: @DavidFoster Sorry about that, I added it.

Comment: Can you show the whole error message? Your code works for me, as it should, although I'm not testing in flask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop across the length of one of the lists (`up_part` in this case) and divide them by the corresponding value in the second list:

```
def element_wise_division(up_part, down_part):
    output=[]
    for x in range(len(up_part)):
        output.append(up_part[x]/down_part[x])
    return output
```

This isn't overly efficient, but is simple to read and debug. Be aware that an error would be raised if the `down_part` is shorter than the `up_part`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to pair up same indexes of lists - for unequal lenght lists, the non-paired of the longer list will be dropped (use [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) in that case)

```
print(list(zip(up_part, down_part)))
```

will print

```
[(4.0, 6.0), (4.0, 8.94427190999916), (2.0, 6.928203230275509), (5.0, 7.348469228349535)]
```

---

Full code:

```
from operator import truediv 

def calc_cosine(up_part, down_part):
    cosines=[]
    for data in zip(up_part, down_part):
        cosines.append(truediv(*data))
    return cosines

up_part = [4.0, 4.0, 2.0, 5.0]
down_part= [6.0, 8.94427190999916, 6.928203230275509, 7.348469228349535]

print(calc_cosine(up_part, down_part))
```

prints:

```
[0.6666666666666666, 0.4472135954999579, 0.2886751345948129, 0.6804138174397716]
```

or in short:

```
from operator import truediv 

up_part = [4.0, 4.0, 2.0, 5.0]
down_part= [6.0, 8.94427190999916, 6.928203230275509, 7.348469228349535]

print([ truediv(*c) for c in zip(up_part, down_part)])
```

Comment: Any idea why this will work when their `map` version won't?

Comment: @Heap the OP tries to truediv a list through another list. I create pairs of numbers from those lists (using zip) and  feed each pair into truediv. So I divide numbers, they dont.

Comment: No, the OP also feeds pairs of numbers into truediv. And it works: https://repl.it/repls/BasicEthicalCron

Comment: @Heap but not with a for loop like he asked for - for debugging purposes. He gets an error with his thing and wanted a more debuggable version with for loop.

Comment: Ah, ok. That might be a good reason. They didn't mention debuggability and so I somewhat ignored the for loop request.

Answer (score 0):

you can use list comprehension with `zip`:

```
def calc_cosine(up_part, down_part):
    return [u / d for u, d in zip(up_part, down_part)]
```